# Startup of ECS Fargate task fails with ResourceInitializationError mount.nfs4 Connection timed out

Tags: amazon-ecs, fargate, amazon-efs

When starting up an Amazon ECS task with launch type FARGATE it fails with the following reason:

```
ResourceInitializationError: failed to invoke EFS utils commands to set up EFS volumes: command failed with 32: failed to execute command to invoke EFS utils: mount.nfs4:

Connection timed out
```

The fargate task is a docker image that needs to mount EFS as persistent storage.

Why is the connection timing out?

Comment: Could you please provide some more context to this? There doesn't seem to be a question asked either.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Edited with a proper question and a bit more context. Are there more improvements I could make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underlying reason:

The ECS service's network access security group did not have permission to access EFS.

Solution:

Add an inbound rule for type `NFS` in the security group as described in this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/tutorial-efs-volumes.html#efs-security-group